# Displaying to top link on scroll of page

Tags: css

I'm trying to display an arraow on scroll of the page this way which has as id #top :

```
.scroll #top{
  opacity: .2;
}
```

But, this wouldn't work. When I try to debug it using chrome and try to copy the CSS path via its tool, and after scrolling the page, I get `#top` as a CSS path instead of `.scroll #top`. What's wrong, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show us your html code. I assume there's javascript involved too?

Comment: @FabianLauer, `<a id="top" href="#"><img src="/img/arrow.png"></a>`

Comment: No JS? You wrote about "on scroll", you'll need javascript to listen for scroll events.